# React, Ruby on Rails: jsx vs html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using the react-rails gem to integrate react with rails, and I'm conflicted on how I should organize my code.

Is it preferable that I have my core html in the `html.erb` files or in the `jsx` files? Currently, I basically made everything a component. All I do in my `html.erb` files is using the `react_component` helper to call those components. For example, I would have a `ProfileShow.js.jsx` file for my profile page and a `EditPost.js.jsx` for my edit post page.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Have a look at this link https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers the introduction could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer move my react-component's code to js-files. And link them using `react_component` helper method. It isn't good practice to write your js-code in views.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I was asking where I should put most of my core html. Should I render them as components even if they're used only once, or should I write them in html.erb?

Comment: I usually render them as components. And all views look very thin.

Comment: By thin do you mean concise?

Comment: Exactly, sorry, for my English:)

Comment: No worries! It wasn't a wrong expression. I was just making sure I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.
One of the best solutions I seen so far is to write your react jsx components in an  app/assets/javascripts/components folder.

Setup a react gem  like https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails
that would help with passing on data as props to the view layer as these would be accessible outside react.

I hope this helps.

Cheers.